# Imageresizer RemoteReader Not Displaying GIF Images

Tags: gif, imageresizer

It appears as though none of my GIF photos are displaying with Remote Reader. JPEGs are working fine. GIF is an accepted extension. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Can you provide more details, such as the diagnostics page output and the exact error message? Use [gist.github.com](http://gist.github.com) for the longer bits.

Comment: The only error message in resizer.debug.ashx. The only error message is that I disabled the Disk Cache.

Comment: What does the image request return? 500? 404?

Comment: It's likely the remote server is doing something wrong with the mime type, so it would be best to include the response HTTP headers for the original resource in your question.

Comment: Sorry I haven't gotten back to this question. I disabled it for now, but I will come back to it and edit the questions with the response headers. Thanks.